# Start and end an independent sub-session in Python

Tags: python

How to implement the following idea, in which different jobs are done separately (isolated) without exiting the same Python main session.

```
>>> Session.Start()
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> ...         #do the job
>>> Session.End()
```

and another session using other packages:

```
>>> Session.Start()
>>> from numpy import *
>>> x = array([1,2,3,4])
>>> ...         #do the job
>>> Session.End()
```

Comment: What exactly is this `Session`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @jadkik94 `Session` is **the question**! As you see however, `Session.Start` isolates the session and so there are no conflict between similar objects from different packages.

Comment: @Developer I know it's the question :), but where did you get this object from? Edit: Oh ok, you want to *create* such an object... sorry

Comment: Do you want to do that in the interpreter or a script you will run?

Comment: @WaleedKhan Without this idea, we cannot use `from sympy import *` and `from numpy import *`, for example due to conflict of similar named objects. Also `import sympy` or `import sympy as sym` etc (you may suggest) are not our goal.

Comment: @jadkik94 Yes in an interpreter.

Comment: @Developer The point of namespacing is to remove conflict. If you're going to ignore that and import the entire symbol table, you've just *defeated the conflict-resolution mechanism*. Use namespaces.

Comment: By Session, do you mean a sub-process which run asynchronous in the background?

Comment: @Crazyshezy I think what is meant is to save/restore everything in the global scope with the session. Like having 2 separate global scopes while in the interpreter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not recommended, this is what you can do:

- Starting a session saves the state of `sys.modules`, `sys.path`, and the globals.
- Whatever happens will have some effect of these (and maybe others).
- Stopping a session will restore the state of the previously started session.

You should note that this is not perfect, and not recommended. I can really not see what is wrong with `import sympy` instead of `from sympy import *`.

**Edit:**

It seems having access and modifying the global scope is not easy and will get you in a lot of trouble... See this for example:

```
class Session(object):
    def __init__(self, gref):
        self.init()
        self.gref = gref

    def init(self):
        self.modules = {}
        self.path = None
        self.glob = {}

    def start(self):
        import sys
        self.modules = sys.modules.copy()
        self.path = sys.path[:]
        self.glob = self.gref.copy()
        self.gref['test'] = 'abc'

    def stop(self):
        import sys
        sys.modules = self.modules.copy()
        sys.path = self.path[:]
        for k in self.gref.keys():
            del self.gref[k]
        self.gref.update(self.glob)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.glob)
```

Running it:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sessionpy import Session
>>> s = Session(globals())
>>> before = 123
>>> s.start()
>>> after = 456
>>> s.stop()
>>> after
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'after' is not defined
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 18, in <module>
    import problem_report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 15, in <module>
    from email.encoders import encode_base64
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    setattr(sys.modules['email'], _name, importer)
KeyError: 'email'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'after' is not defined
>>> before
123
>>>
```

You can see it works (as `after` raises a `NameError`) but there's another problem arising with some module in the `sys.excepthook`. I can only imagine the problems you will have with 2 huge libraries such as `sympy` and `numpy`.

**Note:**
If you just want a simple thing running, you can just mess with the globals, and you'll be kind of OK.

Comment: It just is not neat to have sympy prefix for any objects in it. It makes messy the things. We may run another Python session (so another window) to do the job isolated but it is not perfect too! right?

Comment: @Developer Actually, it is.

Comment: @Developer With the method I mention in my answer, you might stumble in lots of weird things when working on other stuff... so you might not want to get into this mess :) And I'm trying to make it actual code, and it looks like a *really* big mess.

Comment: @Developer: Using `import *` is much messier.  Using prefixed names is nice and clean.

Comment: @BrenBarn In this case, I think running them separately is what OP is looking for...

Comment: @BrenBarn jadkik94 is correct. The whole idea is simple: to avoid running another Python console separately. While in only one Python console to avoid conflict where we prefer to use `import *` due to avoiding using prefix etc.

Comment: May you give some hint how to save the info and load them back efficiently?

Comment: @Developer Check my edit to see what I mean :)

Comment: It does job just perfect. BTW, Happy very lovely year and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Developer Happy new year! But keep in mind that is not the optimal way to do this. But as long as it works... :)